# How to save records in xml file?

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee

in my web application i want to save records from data base table to  xml file by using jdom, but the problem is that just one record is saved.

Test_xml.java

```
 List<User> users = session.selectList("dao.UserDao.findAll") ;
for (User u : users) {
       try {

    Element company = new Element("user");
    Document doc = new Document(company);
    Element staff = new Element("data");
     staff.setAttribute(new Attribute("id", u.getId()));
     staff.setAttribute(new Attribute("name", u.getName()));
    doc.getRootElement().addContent(staff);
    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
    xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("c:\\user.xml"));
    out.println("File Saved!");
  } catch (IOException io) {
    out.println(io.getMessage());
  }
```

i want to have this structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
<data id="1" name="Nancy" />
<data id="2" name="Jennifer" />
</user>
```

Help please,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep overwriting the saved records. You are creating new XMLOutputer inside your for loop, and use it save one user to the user.xml file.

So your file will contain only the last user from the users list.

You need to create the Root element outside the for loop, inside the loop append to it children node (staff in your code), and then after the loop, use XMLOutputer to output the whole document to the xml.

Comment: Thanks it works, i have another problem with the id, i change it to int type but  staff.setAttribute(new Attribute(String,String )); doesn't accept int, i tried u.getId().toString()  but it didn't work.

Comment: new Attribute("id",""+u.getId())

Answer (score 0):

To have this structure you can do:

```
    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
    Element company = new Element("user");
     Document doc = new Document(company);

    for (User u : users) {
        try {

     Element staff = new Element("data");
     staff.setAttribute(new Attribute("id", u.getId()));
     staff.setAttribute(new Attribute("name", u.getName()));
     doc.getRootElement().addContent(staff);

     xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
     xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("c:\\user.xml"));

   } catch (IOException io) {
     //@todo manage your exception
   }

}
```

if your id is an int you can do :

```
staff.setAttribute(new Attribute("id",Integer.toString(u.getId())));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have the type of id is String, but staff.setAttribute(new Attribute("id", u.getId())); didn't accept u.getId() if it's id, i tried to convert it to String but didn't work